# How to Copy/Paste with Format

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, copy-paste, textblock

How can I **Copy** any content like this question as example and **Paste** it into RichtextBox or TextBlock in a WPF application *With* content decorations like bold , italic , images , links , HTML .., etc ?

Please point me to a solution or even a WPF control or anything related

I just want an html container !!

Comment: Search for "html editor wpf" gives this link: http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor . Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE is a platform independent WYSIWYG form plug in and it does exactly what you describe:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php

Try copying your question and pasting it into the example above to see the results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you might have missed the point, the question was about pasting into a WPF RichTextBox control.

Comment: Can I add this inside browser and load it to my wpf application ?

Comment: Thanks, You really help me putting my feet on the way